# Compare multiple columns from one file with multiple columns of another file using awk?

Tags: awk

I want to compare first 2 characters of col1 of file1 with col1 of file2 if col3 of file1 is same as col3 of file2 , provided col4 in file2 equals to TRUE. I tried something :-

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS};(NR==FNR) 
{a[substr($1,1,2),$3]=$1;next}(($1,$3)in a) && $4==TRUE ' file1 file2 > outfield
```

file 1

```
AE1267453617238|BIDKFXXXX|United Arab Emirates|
PL76UTYVJDYGHU9|ABSFXXJBW|Poland|
GB76UTRTSCLSKJ|FVDGXXXUY|Russia|
```

file 2

```
AE|^AE[0-9]{2}[0-9]{24}|United Arab Emirates|TRUE|
PL|^PL[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{10}[0-9]{4}|Poland|FALSE|
GB|^GB[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{3}|Europe|TRUE
```

expected output :-

```
AE1267453617238|BIDKFXXXX|United Arab Emirates|
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just simply cascade the multiple conditions with a `&&` as below. Remember your expected output is on the first file, so you need to process the second file first

```bash
awk -F'|' ' FNR == NR { 
            if ( $4 == "TRUE" ) m[$1] = $3 ; next }{ k = substr($1,1,2) } k in m && m[k] == $3' file2 file1
```

The part `m[$1] = $3` creates a hash-map of the `$1` with the value of `$3` in the second file, which is then used in the first file to compare against only the first two characters of `$1` i.e. `substr($1,1,2)`. To avoid redundant use of `substr(..)`, the value is extracted into a variable `k` and reused subsequently.

Answer (score 1):

If the matches must be on the same line number in each file:

```
awk -F \| '
FNR==NR && $4 == "TRUE" {a[NR,1]=$1; a[NR,3]=$3}
FNR!=NR && $3 == a[FNR,3] &&
$1 ~ "^"a[FNR,1]' file2 file1
```

If the matches can be on any line (every line of file1 is checked against every line of file2, duplicate matches aren't printed):

```
awk -F \| '
FNR==NR {++l}
FNR==NR && $4 == "TRUE" {a[NR,1]=$1; a[NR,3]=$3}
FNR!=NR {
    for (i=1; i<=l; ++i) {
            if ($3 == a[i,3] && $1 ~ "^"a[i,1])
            c[$0]==0
     }
}
END {
    for (i in c)
        print i
}' file2 file1
```

Note the order files are given. file2 (which contains TRUE and FALSE), goes first. I also used regex instead of substr, so the characters should be alphanumeric only, if not, go back to substr.

Comment: Never use a variable name `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code.

Comment: @EdMorton fair point, but I feel like that's a bug in the font. The distinction is a lot clearer with a curve at the bottom of ell. Examples here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71353/why-is-it-still-common-to-use-too-similar-glyphs-for-1-and-l-in-monospace

Comment: You can't control what font someone else will read your code using, and often neither can they. Not using `l` as a variable name has been a rule forever and still applies, just google "don't use l for variable name" or similar for examples,

Comment: e.g. at http://www.oualline.com/style/c03.html it says `Never use I (lowercase L ) or O (uppercase O ) as variable or constant names....` and at https://wiki.c2.com/?BadVariableNames it says `Some of the worst I've seen are using the lowercase "ell" and uppercase "oh" as variables:...` and https://betterprogramming.pub/clean-code-naming-b90740cbae12 says `never use a small letter l (el), a capital letter I (eye) ...,` and https://www.codemodes.com/variable-naming-rules/ says `Never use l (lowercase L) or O (uppercase O) as variable names`, etc., etc.

Comment: Like I said it's a fair point. But I still think it's a bug in the font.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your code:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS};(NR==FNR) 
{a[substr($1,1,2),$3]=$1;next}(($1,$3)in a) && $4==TRUE ' file1 file2 > outfield
```

newlines matter to awk. This:

```
NR==FNR
{ print }
```

is not the same as this:

```
NR==FNR { print }
```

The first one is actually the same as:

```
NR==FNR { print }
1 { print }
```

Also when you want to output the contents of a file (`file1` in your case) it's usually better to read the OTHER file into memory and then compare the values from the target file against that so you can just print it as you go. So you should be doing `awk 'script' file2 file1`, not `awk 'script' file1 file2`, and writing a script based on that.

Try this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|" }
NR==FNR {
    if ( $4 == "TRUE" ) {
        map[$1] = $3
    }
    next
}
{ key = substr($1,1,2) }
(key in map) && (map[key] == $3)
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
AE1267453617238|BIDKFXXXX|United Arab Emirates|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\| '
  NR==FNR{ 
        a[$3,1]=$1; 
        a[$3,4]=$4; 
        next 
  } 
  substr($1,1,2) == a[$3,1] && a[$3,4] == "TRUE" { print }
' file2.txt file1.txt 

AE1267453617238|BIDKFXXXX|United Arab Emirates|
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for arrays of arrays (or change to pseudo-multi-dim-array syntax, `a[$3,1]` instead of `a[$3][1]`, etc. as that'd work in any awk).